# Xcode 6 does not localize Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, localization, swift, interface-builder, xcode6

**Xcode 6 Beta 4** using Swift.

I use localization in my project and I have experience in localization from Xcode 5.

Localization in program code using `NSLocalizedString()` works fine.
Localization of `Info.plist` strings work fine, too.

When it comes to localize the strings from Interface Builder it only works in *Interface Builder* preview but not in simulator and not on my device (iPhone 5S).

Am I missing something or can anyone confirm this as a bug in in Xcode 6 Beta 4?

Comment: have you tried upgrading to beta 5, could be a problem with the simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple release notes of XCode 6 GM covers this :

> Localization: 
>   A storyboard or XIB will not localize correctly if all of the following three conditions are true:
>   The storyboard or XIB uses size classes.
>   The base localization and the build target are set to Universal.
>   The build targets iOS 7.0.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the problem is with the size classes.

If "Use Size Classes" checkbox is enabled for storyboard, the Xcode actually generates 3 versions of it (`"<Name>.storyboard", "<Name>~ipad.storyboard" and "<Name>~iphone.storyboard"`).

So iOS just tries to load .strings file which name matches the name of active storyboard (`<Name>~iphone.strings` in case app is running on the iPhone). And being not able to find that file, it falls back to Base localization.

There are a couple of ways to work around this bug:

1. The most obvious one. Just disable size classes for the storyboard.
2. If you need size classes, you can add localized `<Name>~iphone.strings` and `<Name>~ipad.strings` files to the project manualy and copy your translations over.