# Storyboard not localizing when built for ios 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

I have my entire project set up with a single Storyboard with autolayout complete for iOS 8. My project also targets iOS 7. In interface builder I believe that I accidentally clicked some setting and now at run-time the app does not load the localized strings when the single file is built for iOS 7.

In the file inspector of the Storyboard if I have the file set to build for iOS 8 everything localizes fine but if I set it to build to iOS 7 then no localized strings load at all.

Note: If the storyboard is set to build for iOS 8 and I attempt to run the app for iOS 7 it immediately crashes with "Could not instantiate class named UIStoryBoardShowSegueTemplate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and already asked it here: [Xcode 6 does not localize Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989208/xcode-6-does-not-localize-interface-builder)

The release notes for Xcode 6 covers this:

> Localization A storyboard or XIB will not localize correctly if all of the following three conditions are true: The storyboard or XIB uses size classes. The base localization and the build target are set to Universal. The build targets iOS 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

set your Storyboard interface builder document,  "Builds for" to `iOS 7` not `iOS8`

[image]

Comment: When I do that the file doesn't localize

Comment: Yes and that causes the problem! Setting that to iOS 7 makes it not localize