# Localization works in iOS 7 but not in iOS 8

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, ios8, ios-simulator

I have localized versions of a file `hello.txt` in folders `en.lproj` and `fr.lproj`.
When I run the following code on iOS 7 simulator with language set to French, the French version is loaded. But with iOS 8 in French, I only get English... Why?

```
println (NSLocale.preferredLanguages().first!)
println (NSBundle.mainBundle().preferredLocalizations.first!)
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource ("hello", ofType: "txt")
let text = NSString (contentsOfURL: NSURL (fileURLWithPath: path!)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
println (text!)
```

Comment: This is a bug in Xcode 6.1 (see release notes). It is fixed in 6.2

Comment: @zisoft Thanks, I should have guessed this, I was scratching my head for too long... If you add the reference as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known issues in Xcode 6.1:

> Localization and Keyboard settings (including 3rd party keyboards) are
>   not correctly honored by Safari, Maps, and developer apps in the iOS
>   8.1 Simulator. [NSLocale currentLocale] returns en_US and only the English and Emoji keyboards are available. (18418630, 18512161)

Problem exists since [Xcode 6 GM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989208/xcode-6-does-not-localize-interface-builder/25763777#25763777)

Comment: This problem exists in iOS 8.1.  It did not exist in the iOS 8.0 simulator, although other CFPreferences bugs were present in 8.0.